# Django form save with post_save signal causing conflict

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-signals

I have a Physical_therapy_order model and an Event model (an event has foreignkey to Physical_therapy_order). I have a view which allows a user to create a new event. It also has a form with 3 fields from the Physical_therapy_order model.

```
def PTEventCreateView(request, pt_pk):
    #get the pt order and create an a form for that order
    pt_order = get_object_or_404(Physical_therapy_order, pk=pt_pk)
    ptform = PT_schedule_form(instance=pt_order)

    if request.POST:
        eventform = PTEventForm(data=request.POST)
        ptform = PT_schedule_form(data=request.POST, instance=pt_order)

        if eventform.is_valid() and ptform.is_valid():
            #I do some checks here that compare data across the two forms.
            # if everything looks good i mark keep_saving=True so I can 
            # continue to save all the data provided in the two forms
            if keep_saving:
                ptform.save()
                eventform.save()
            #...send user to succss page
```

This works just FINE EXCEPT: my PTEvent model has a function attached to its post_save signal. This function pulls the event's related pt_order and makes some modifications to it. Now, if i save the eventform first then the changes from the signal don't happen. if i save the ptform first the ptform changes get discarded and the changes from the signal happen.

THIS IS IMPORTANT: The ptform is editing three entirely different fields than the post_save signal. So its not like they're modifying the same data, only the same model instance. I thought a form only saves the fields in its meta.fields attribute. Why would this be happening? Also, if i save the ptform first, then when eventsform is saved shouldn't the signal use the updated physical_therapy_order? I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because of cached objects.

What I would suggest is

- Save `eventform` first
- Get new instance of `pt_order` either querying db or through saved instance of eventform
- And then re-create form and save.

Sample code change:

```
# your code
if keep_saving:
    evt = eventform.save()
    # I'm not sure exact name of your field name for pt_order in Event model, change appropriately
    newptform = PT_schedule_form(data=request.POST, instance= evt.pt_order)
    newpt = newptform.save()
```

Comment: thanks, worked. 2 points: I still don't get why saving my original ptform doesn't work: I thought saving a form only saves its fields, so even if it has a cached physical_therapy_order, what does it matter. Also, fyi I tried a method similar to yours where i used Physical_therapy_order.get(pk=pt_pk), and then tried to reload a form and save it: This didn't work. But your method of getting the PT order from eventform.save() worked nicely.

Comment: @rsp, The problem is because, object attributes are stale, as new attributes are saved in DB. I believe ` Physical_therapy_order.get(pk=pt_pk)` should also work. Did you do this after saving `eventform`?